# How to activate keyboard accelerator shown on Internet Explorer 11 notification bar?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

[image]

So how can I press **Show all content** button using keyboard?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> worked in IE 10 (Windows 8), because notification bar accelerators have had precedence while the bar was displayed, but this no longer works in IE 11 (which came with upgrade to Windows 8.1), where pressing Alt+letter invokes standard commands, not those suggested on notification bar.

For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> opens **Safety** dropdown menu even if the notification bar is displayed:

[image]

The question targets all possible notification bars, including well-known ones for downloading files.

[image]

IE version in detail: **11.0.9600.18538**

Comment: Works as described/wanted here (IE11 Windows 10), and Alt+S isn't a standard IE shortcut, so can you explain which "standard command" it's invoking?

Comment: "Standard command" for Alt+S in English IE 11 is **Safety** dropdown menu. Question updated. (Windows 8.1.)

Comment: Ahhh, that bar no one uses anymore. gotcha.. :)   Anyhow, using Tab should get you to that bar and it's buttons, and then you can use Space to press the button.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 – does this behavior when "that bar no one uses anymore" is visible persist also on Windows 10? If yes, then we have universal answer – either hide the bar or use tabs+space.